# Node js 0.10.7: cluster support for udp dgram?

Tags: node.js, udp, cluster-computing

I'm trying to run following node js application as mentioned https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2194

```
var util = require("util"),
  dgram = require("dgram"),
  cluster = require('cluster');

var udp = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
var port = 1190;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  util.log("starting udp server on port " + port);
  udp.on("error", function (error) {
    util.log("failed to bind to UDP port - " + error)
  });
  udp.bind(port);
}
```

The app exits immediately with the following output:

```
23 May 23:22:13 - starting udp server on port 1190
23 May 23:22:13 - starting udp server on port 1190

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write ENOTSUP - cannot write to IPC channel.
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at ChildProcess.target.send (child_process.js:455:16)
    at Worker.send (cluster.js:401:21)
    at sendInternalMessage (cluster.js:394:10)
    at handleResponse (cluster.js:177:5)
    at respond (cluster.js:192:5)
    at Object.messageHandler.queryServer (cluster.js:242:5)
    at handleMessage (cluster.js:197:32)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
```

Does anyone know what is going on? When running this without cluster, everything is fine.
It seems that cluster does not support udp?

Some specs:

```
Window 7 x64
node js 0.10.7
```

Comment: i ran into a the exact same issue (was trying to do a `socket.send(...)` on a udp socket), works fine without the cluster environment. do you have anything new to that issue?

Comment: it appears that it is working fine on linux but not on windows.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zaphod1984/5668274

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. I did not check on any linux environment, but it seems you came to same conclusion regarding Win 7 x64. I guess we need to create a bug issue for this

Comment: already did: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5587 they confirmed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It says in the link your provided that support for UDP clustering was added in v0.11.14.  It is likely that you simply need to update your version of node.js